# Funcion Javascript para no leer saltos de linea en blanco

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo txt con javascript y convertirlo en JSON, pero los archivos al final tienen un salto de linea en blanco

> Ejemplo del archivo TXT

1. (0,"A":RED,1)
2. (1,"B":GREEN,4)
  3.

Esta es mi funcion

```
                function parseContent(content) {
    //Couper chaque ligne du fichier aprés saut de ligne
    var lines = content.split("\n");
    //Array à stocker les donnés
    var result = [];
    //Creation de l'automate
    var automateObject;
    var title;
    var currentline
    //Parcourir tout le fichier
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      //Pour creer l'onbjet automate
        if(i == 0){
          currentline = lines[i].split("\n");
          currentline = lines[i].replace(/[\(\)]/g, '');  
          currentline = currentline.replace(/,/g, '');   
          currentline = currentline.split(" ");
          automateObject = new Automate(parseInt(currentline[1]),parseInt(currentline[2]),parseInt(currentline[3]));
        } else {
            //variable pour stocker le titre et la couleur
            var tam;
            //variable pour couper chaque ligne du fichier
            currentline = lines[i].split("\n");
            if(currentline.length > 0){
              //Enlever les parenthese de la chaine de characters
              currentline = lines[i].replace(/[\(\)]/g, '');
              //Enlever les citations de la chaine
              currentline = currentline.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
              //Couper la chaine en 3 morceaux
              currentline = currentline.split(",",3);
              //Couper le deuxieme atribut pour obtenir le nom de lien et la couleur
              title = currentline[1].split(":");
              //Creation d'un object de type automate
              const etat = new Etat(parseInt(currentline[0]),title[0],title[1],parseInt(currentline[2]));
              //Ajouter l'object dans l'array
              result.push(etat);
            } 
        }
    } 
automateObject.Etats = result;        
      //Conversion de l'array en JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(automateObject));
}
```

Con el punto length trato de evitar que lee el salto de linea en blanco, pero lamantablemente esa linea si tiene un tamaño y es 1

Como podria decir que no lea los saltos de linea en blanco?

Comment: ¿Por qué estás haciendo un split una segunda vez en `lines[i].split("\n");`? Si ya habías separado los saltos de línea al inicio

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: que lea cada linea del txt pero ignorando la linea en blanco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de intentar algunas de sus respuesta, no logre resolverlo de esa forma, por ello decidi usar una condicion a cada momento que se lea una linea

```
if(lines[i].length > 1){
}
```

y con esto evito que haga todo el proceso de cada linea si la linea es una linea en blanco

Comment: utilizaria por las dudas `lines[i].trim().length > 1` para evitar espacios en blanco

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer esto

```
currentline = lines[i].trim().split("\n");
```

O bien, si más arriba tienes un "for" por el cual te recorres las líneas, haz el TRIM ahí y así te quitas las comprobaciones. Es decir, lines[i] seguro viene de otro split("\n"). Pues ahí pon el TRIM.

```
for (i = 0; i < contenido.trim().split('\n').length; i++)
```

Resumiendo, es mejor excluir esa línea vacía desde el principio y así minimizas los errores.

Editado: pon esto arriba.

```
var lines = content.trim().split("\n");
```

Comment: acabo de agregar toda la funcion que utiliso

Comment: no me funciono.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner las  3 últimas líneas del fichero?

Comment: 1. (0,"A":RED,1)
2. (1,"B":GREEN,4)
3.